# How to split an integer array into two

Tags: java, arrays

I want to split my array into two parts an upper and a lower
but it wont work
it just prints the sort for me
I put random print statements to make sure the condition is true and it is

In the even condition it reads the if and the for statement 
but in the odd it only reads the if statement

Here is my code

```
public static int GetTheLowerHalfandUpperHalf(int[] array) {
    int size = array.length;
    int even = size%2;
   if (even == 0) {
       //print the lower half
       for(int i=0; i==even;i++) {
           int[] upper;
           upper = new int[i];
           System.out.println("The UPPER half is: "+Arrays.toString(upper));
           System.out.println("Q3 = " +median(upper));
       }
       //print the upper half
       for (int j=(even+1);j==size;j++) {
          int[] lower;
        lower=new int[j];
        System.out.println("The UPPER half is: "+Arrays.toString(lower)); 
        System.out.println("Q1 = " +median(lower));
       }


    } else if ((array.length % 2) != 0) { 
        //print the lower half
       for (int i=0;i==(Q2-1);i++) {
           int[] upper;
           upper = new int[i];
           System.out.println("The UPPER half is: "+Arrays.toString(upper));
           System.out.println("Q3 = " +median(upper));
       }
       //print the upper half
       for(int j=(Q2+1) ;j==size ;j++ ){
        int[] lower;
        lower=new int[j];
        System.out.println("The UPPER half is: "+Arrays.toString(lower));
        System.out.println("Q1 = " +median(lower));
    }
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Q2 is the median of the whole array

Comment: The second segment of a `for` loop defines when it will run, not when it will stop.  For instance, `for (int j=(even+1);j==size;j++)` would normally look more like `for (int j=(even+1);j<size;j++)`.  If that made sense to you, then this might, too: your first if statement only runs if `even == 0`, so your first for loop, `for(int i=0; i==even;i++)`, will only run when `i` is also 0.

Comment: This: `int even = size%2;` will mean that `even` will be 0 for an even number, and 1 for an odd number. This: `for(int i=0; i==even;i++) {` would mean that that loop will never execute for an even number. At the very least you would need something of the sort: `int halfArrayMarker = (int) array.size / 2;` and you then replace `for(int i=0; i==even;i++) {` with `for(int i=0; i==halfArrayMarker;i++) {`.

When you say `median of the whole array`, do you mean the average of all the values or does it mark the mid point of the array?

Comment: i mean the mid point of the array.

Comment: and thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

**Alternate Solution:**

```
int[] firstHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, array.length/2);
int[] secondHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, array.length/2, array.length);
```

Then of course you could perform your `median()` method:

```
int firstMedian = median(firstHalf);
```

Remember, you don't have to reinvent the wheel, but you do have to make the wheel fit your car.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea because what hallens if you arraylist is not a just number it will crash.. Can you explain a bit more of your content?

Answer (score 0):

```java
// double median(int[] arr, int start, int end)
double hiMedian = median(arr, 0, array.length / 2);
double loMedian = median(arr, array.length / 2, array.length);
```

Please note, that make an array copy in general case is not recommended. It is enough just to calculate ranges' first and end indices.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  In particular, how does it average the middle two values when the array has an even number of elements?